# handling Http put method in REST

Tags: rest-api

```
    @HttpPut
    global static String updateCase(RestRequest req)
    {
        string cname = req.params.get('Accountname');
        Account acc =[Select ID, Name, Type, BillingState from Account where Name = :cname];
         Attachment a = new Attachment();
        a.Name='test.png';
        a.parentId=acc.id;
        a.Body=req.requestBody;
        insert a;
        return 'process success';
    }
```

I get invaluid type Http method: system.restrequest error in this code ,i dont kno how to solve it

Comment: Can you post whole code that you wrote.It will be helpful to go through.Including how you declared class and also the REST context system classes

Comment: hi mohith i got my code working ,check my answer

Answer (score 2):

The way that RestRequest and RestResponse are accessed changed in api version 24.0 so any code with version 24.0 or later will need to access them using the new RestContext object:

```
@HttpPost
global Static Map<String,String> doPut() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
}
```

The old way was

```
@HttpPost
global Static Map<String,String> doPut(RestRequest req, RestResponse res){}
```